# Fill enclosed path in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, path

I'm having difficulties with a really basic concept in Inkscape. How do I fill an enclosed path that has a line going into it? I've combined the original two paths to form one path, but filling it doesn't actually fill it. The only way I can seem to get it to work are hacks like adding a background object filled with the right color. Here's an example of my issue:

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Once we had combined paths we may not be able to fill an an enclosed area as expected:

[image]

In the combined path above the line on the lower right will also be treated as a part of a filled area, leading to the filling artifact.

To overcome this we should apply fills on non-combined paths, or we have to **break apart** the objects before we apply the fill:

[image]

If this is not possible we may use the *Bucket Fill* tool (<kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>F7</kbd> ). This tool will create an additional filled object within an enclosed area (see also [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27779/filling-drawing)):

[image]

Comment: The 2nd option worked for me. I just had to break it apart into two different pieces at the right place. Option 3 always looks ugly to me, because it leaves that weird white line.

Comment: To remove the "weird white line" we can a) define a stroke to the newly created fill object or b) make it a tiny bit larger then move it down below the outlines.

Answer (score 10):

I am brand new to Inkskape and I found this question as the first search result for `inkskape closed path fill`. Unfortunately, the paint bucket added aliasing artifacts and I spent 15 further minutes trying to find the fill tool. For future searchers:

Fill a closed path by **selecting the path and clicking a color in the pallete at bottom**

Comment: This only works if the path fully encloses a surface. If your path is hollow, using the bucket tool and expanding the resulting fill area is the way to go.