# Filling vector paths partially in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, svg

I am trying to understand how to approach a problem where I have a vector path that I only want to fill only a part of the path of.

For example, here is an unclosed inkscape path that I want to fill the "D" section of.
[image]

The shape is not closed, so filling it causes this:

[image]

if I move the point slightly.

Is there a way to avoid this kind of issue?

Comment: [Related question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/30433/68027).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [paint bucket tool](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Bucket.html). It will create a new closed path congruent with the *D* shape.

You can group the original path and the paint path, so the move around together.