# Add a line to a shape, and color the new space

Tags: inkscape

I am trying to take a shape like this,

[image]

And add a line to it like this,

[image]

I want to be able to shade the bottom section that gets created by this separate from the top, as per the drawing book I am following along with. I have tried Path > Combine and Path > Union, but these do not give the results I am looking for.

Comment: For areas more complex than above see https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30433/fill-enclosed-path-in-inkscape

Answer (score 1):

Here's a cartoon:

[image]

1. An ellipse and a closed shape for the rest of the cylinder were drawn. The ellipse is rotated a little. The other shape is drawed with the pen tool. Something like a perspective has been at least tried.
2. The shapes have got solid fill colors
3. One line was drawn with the pen tool
4. The paint bucket was used to fill the closed are with a darker color. The paint bucket creates a new closed shape which can get a stroke automatically, if there was recently drawed something with a stroke. In this case the generated stroke was removed by taking its color off.

Open shapes can be the limits of the paint bucket fill. It works ok, if there is gapless area to fill. This probably was, what you wanted.

5. Not asked, but try also gradient fills. Here a linear 3 stop gradient was drawed between the long edges. Gradients are very plausible shadings for simple curved forms like this. The gradient stop colors (=light red, nearly white and dark red) are as easy to set as single fill colors.

Comment: I tried the paint bucket tool, but it colored outside the line really bad... I tried it again after reading this and it worked this time -.-

Answer (score 0):

I assume the shapes are closed shapes as in 1, and 2 shown below.

3. With the Pen Tool, draw a closed shape over part 2 where you want to cut it.
4. Select both parts 2 and 3. Click `Path` > `Division`
5. Select the new shape created, and fill it with the colour you want.

[image]

Comment: Shape 2 is open in my case. It was basically a free-form line drawn manually onto shape 1. I suppose I can merge the paths or something between 1 and 2?